# Shifting Cells values in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame:

[SampleTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqqDA.png)

Hence the header of the table I imported is divided in two cells I need to shift the cells of the first two columns to shift up. And then to shift the 3 and 4 up. For it to look like this:

[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ea4F.png)

I have tried

```
df.at[1,'x'] = None
```

But that just deletes de value without shifting any cell.

[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXHM9.png)

Comment: Please do include your sample / output / expected data in text form, not images.

Comment: Please df.to_dict() for your input datafame to this question.

Comment: Are AB and CD in the index or rows in the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Get the header with

```
df.columns = df.loc[0].iloc[:2].tolist() + df.columns[2:].tolist()
df = df.loc[1:].reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  4
```